# Perl Single Quote replacement

Tags: perl

I've been struggling for the last days in regards to a character replacement in Perl:

I have a String which is surrounded by single quotes, yet, inside that String, I have a name which contains a single quote, let's say **O'Neil**. Now, given the fact that my String is surrounded by single quotes, Perl recognizes the single quote in the Name, as being the end of the String.

Surrounding the entire string in double quotes is not an option, since it's build from an URL.

Now, I did some research and didn't find anything, now I'm asking y'all:

I've tried to play around with the following syntax:

`$Daten =~ s/\'/\\'/g;` which of course doesn't work...

`$Daten` is the entire string which contains the Name **O'Neil***

Now, I want to replace the single quote, with a backslash quote: **' -> \'**

Anyone has any ideas?

Best regards,
Ionut Sanda

Comment: Show more code. It is not clear why you think "Perl recognizes the single quote in the Name, as being the end of the String".

Comment: The string looks exactly like this:
```'USER1:O'NEILL:PATRICK:M:lastname_firstname@company.com'```
of course, username, and e-mail has been modified (to not post it here) - yet, this is the exact format of the string - now, as you can see, the fact that his name contains a single quote, perl recognizez that that ends the string - that quote I want to replace with a backslash quote (exit character)

Comment: `$str=~s#\w\'\w# $&=~s{\'}{\\\'}r; #eig;`

Comment: Is this part of some larger string?

Comment: Show more code. How are you getting this so-called "string" into your Perl script? What is the exact error message? What is the exact code that produces the error message?

Comment: unfortunately, I can't provide more code than this since it's part of multiple scripts...
At compilation there is no error, it only shows and error when accessing the developer tools in the browser, and the error is very generic for the couple if thousands long script: ```Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list```...
This "string" is concatenated from an array:

```my @valueArray = split /:/, $Daten;  
  $Last__bName             = $valueArray[ 1];
  $First__bName            = $valueArray[ 2];
  $E__uMail__bAddress      = $valueArray[ 4];```

Comment: Show more code. `$s=q(':'':''':''''); @a=split/:/,$s; $v1=$a[1]; $v2=$a[2];` works fine.

Comment: Is the 'USER1...' string a constant in the code ? external input ? Does the code tries to 'eval' dynamically generated code ? Is the code generated with 'Here Document' or similar ? Can you provide a small example that will reproduce the error ?

Comment: every bit of the string, user, lastname, firstname, email, and so on are dynamically read from the database. 
After each bit is read, it's concatenated from an array into the ```$Daten``` and then dynamically displayed with html:
```$html .= "<a href=\"javascript: NSAG_SCD_Import('$Daten')\">";
  $html .= "<img src=\"/MRimg/details.png\" alt=\"Details\"></a>";
  
  $html .= "<a href=\"javascript: NSAG_SCD_Import('$Daten')\">$Last__bName</a>";```

Comment: From this comment, your problem is nothing to do with Perl. To contruct a javascript single-quoted string from a perl variable that contains embedded single-quotes, escape them in perl with `$Daten =~ s/'/\\'/g` then use as `$html .= ... NSAG_SCAD_Import('$Daten') ...`. You may also want to protect other javascript escape sequences like `\b`, `\t`, etc

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like following code should comply with your requirements

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $debug = 1;

while( my $line = <DATA> ) {
    $line =~ s/(.*)'(.+)'(.+)'(.*)/$1'$2\\'$3'$4/g;
    print $line if $debug;
}
__DATA__
'USER1:O'NEILL:PATRICK:M:lastname_firstname@company.com'
datax 'USER1:O'NEILL:PATRICK:M:lastname_firstname@company.com' datay
```

output

```
'USER1:O\'NEILL:PATRICK:M:lastname_firstname@company.com'
datax 'USER1:O\'NEILL:PATRICK:M:lastname_firstname@company.com' datay
```

Comment: That's what I want to avoid, another long piece of code. I would really appreciate to be able to replace the simple quote with the backslash quote, in one line...
I tried to replace the ```$line =~ s/(.*)'(.+)'(.+)'(.*)/$1'$2\\'$3'$4/g;``` with my ```$Daten =~ s/(.*)'(.+)'(.+)'(.*)/$1'$2\\'$3'$4/g;``` but it didn't work..
The reason why I want to avoid long code snippets, is because, everytime I will install the application new, or upgrade it, I will have to copy paste the entire code and it's not optimal, since there are over 1000 customization made throughout the application

Answer (score 0):

Well, as you do not provide a sample or your code I have to improvise

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $debug = 1;

while( my $Daten = <DATA> ) {
    $Daten =~ s/(.*)'(.+)'(.+)'(.*)/$1'$2\\'$3'$4/g;  # Magic happens here
    print $Daten if $debug;
}

__DATA__
'USER1:O'NEILL:PATRICK:M:lastname_firstname@company.com'
datax 'USER1:O'NEILL:PATRICK:M:lastname_firstname@company.com' datay
```

output

```
'USER1:O\'NEILL:PATRICK:M:lastname_firstname@company.com'
datax 'USER1:O\'NEILL:PATRICK:M:lastname_firstname@company.com' datay
```

Otherwise I do not have enough information to understand your problem (no sample of data, no snippet of the code).